# URL Rewrite for multiple links or block some of links

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

We have following urls/binding for one website

- test.se.local/*
- test.en.local/*
- test.se.local/cms/*
- test.en.local/cms/*
- test.se.cms.local/*
- test.en.cms.local/*
- test.se.cms.local/cms/*
- test.en.cms.local/cms/*

How do I implement following rewrite?

- test.se.cms.local/* --> test.se.local/*
- test.en.cms.local/* --> test.en.local/*
- test.se.local/cms/* --> test.se.cms.local/cms/*
- test.en.local/cms/* --> test.en.cms.local/cms/*

Or how do I block following links on IIS

- test.se.cms.local/*
- test.en.cms.local/*
- test.se.local/cms/*
- test.en.local/cms/*

The IIS version is IIS7 and IIS8

Comment: Please mention (or tag) what version of IIS you are using.

Comment: Hi, it's IIS 7 and IIS 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a rewrite for every url:

```
 <rule name="Rule1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="test.se.cms.local/*" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="http://test.se.local/{C:2}" />
 </rule>
```